# SSH onto server and execute command to dump database

Tags: ssh, scp

I know what I want to do but I can't quite figure it out.

I want to ssh onto a remote webserver, execute a command to dump a database and then bring down that database.

To complicate matters, I am doing this to a grid server, so the ip addresss will not always be the same.

I have the following idea in my head, but it needs tweaking to get it to work:

```
!/bin/bash
ssh root@server.com
mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxx mydb > mydb.sql
mv mydb.sql /var/www/site/httpdocs/public_folder
wget www.site.com/mydb.sql
```

Any ideas how to make this work? Or perhaps there is a way (within the same script) that I can scp it down instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ssh root@server.com "mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxx mydb" > mydb.sql
```

This will ssh to your server and execute the mysqldump there. The outout will be on `STDOUT` which will be piped through the SSH session and dumped into the local file `mydb.sql`.

The only requirement here is key-based ssh authentication as else you would be asked for your password which doesn't automate too well...

As for your approach, you should **NEVER EVER** put database dumps into a world-readable webroot. This just screams for major security issues. Also you should probably not use the mysql root account for most of your work. Create a new (restricted) database user instead. Generally, you should always try to reduce rights to the very least possible to avoid bad guys exploiting your system.

Comment: Genius!! Works perfectly and the password prompt is fine, I don't want to use ssh keys because it is a live server. I will accept answer as soon as stack overflow lets me. Sweet!

Comment: Generally key-based authentication is more secure than password-based auth (if you handle your keys in a secure manner). Generally, I have password auth completely disabled on all my servers.

Comment: Cheers for the updated post, that is really helpful :) I will also create a db user just for this db :) Many THanks

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues with this.  I used the -t switch to make it work.

```
ssh root@server.com -t "mysqldump -uroot -pxxxxx mydb" > mydb.sql
```

On my server I also added the full path to mysqldump

```
ssh root@server.com -t "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump-uroot -pxxxxx mydb" > mydb.sql
```